# WSO2 EMM Android

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

So I have configured EMM server and it is running perfectly. I have created the bks file and followed all the instructions to generate an apk file with the bks and enabling https. But when I try to enroll a device, it just spins on Authenticating Please Wait. In Android Studio under Device Monitor, I can see it trys to connect to the server and uses the cert I created, but the server never shows anything. I have also tried the admin creds and I tried using some fake creds and still get the same result. Please HELP!!

Comment: Well without code we'd have no idea of how to fix it.  But honestly this sounds like a networking issue, not a programming one.

Comment: I can access it thru the web interface, so I don't think its a network issue. What code would you like to see? Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Since I've never heard of wso before I have no clue.  But I'd start with whatever block of code isn't working right, plus any configuration data that could cause that to do so.  I'd also be checking the server to see if you actually got a hit on the server or not, and if so see where the server is freezing up.  But this question as it is right now is unanswerable.

Comment: Here is the output from the Android Studio Monitor:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By5ad_kyLzt3YUR0bUx2YjlYaW8

Comment: Can you see any error logs in the server?

Comment: Are you using a self signed SSL cert or CA singed certificate?

Comment: Whatever the instructions tell you to use when using a self signed.